# Kotlin (MainActivity.kt) - Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FlutterEngine?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-platform-channel, flutter-engine

e: C:\flutter\POC\contacts\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\contacts\MainActivity.kt: (98, 58): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FlutterEngine?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

- I'm trying to get the  Contacts of a user using platform channels (not plugins) integrated with flutter.
- i added the platform channel sources in MainActivity.kt .
- i added the permission in AndroidManifest.xml.
- I added the UI part in contacts.dart.
- I attached the source images, i tried.

I want to access the contacts of the user using platform channels.
[This is my Ui code file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGxGO.png).
[This is my MainActivity.kt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYaTG.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin (and many other languages) there's the notion of [nullable and not null types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types). In your code you have `flutterEngine` being declared as nullable, but you use it as a not null type, hence the compile error.

You need to describe exactly what should happen when the object `flutterEngine` is null and also when it isn't null. One way would be to use the let [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection):

```
flutterEngine?.let { notNullFlutterEngine ->
    // Use notNullFlutterEngine as you previously did.
    val channel = MethodChannel(notNullFlutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "com.example.contacts")
    channel.invokeMethod("getContacts", contacts)
}
```

I highly recommend reading the previously linked pages in the documentation.